# Access Wrapping Div on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a Web App where one of the pages looks like the following: [image: app]

My issue lies with the 'Remove Item' buttons. I'm unsure exactly of how to access the correct wrapping div using jQuery. The HTML I have is below:

```
            <div id="hwAddition">
                <div>
                    <div id="itemNumber" style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: large; display: inline-block;">Item #</div>
                    <input class="removeItemButton" type="button" value="Remove Item" id="removeItemButton" onclick="removeHWItem()" style="display: inline-block;">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="hwDescription" style="text-decoration: underline;">Description</label>
                        <form:textarea id="hwDescription" type="text"
                            class="form-control short" path="hwDescription"
                            name="hwDescription" placeholder="Description" maxlength="100"
                            rows="2" style="resize: none;" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="hwSerialNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Serial
                            #</label>
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwSerialNumber"
                            name="hwSerialNumber" placeholder="Serial #" maxlength="100" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label for="hwModelNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Model
                            #</label>
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwModelNumber"
                            name="hwModelNumber" placeholder="Model #" maxlength="100" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
            </div>
```

And here is the JS function which I'm unsure of how to write:

```
    function removeHWItem() {
        
    }
```

I don't want to do a `this.remove()` here because I don't want to just remove the button, but instead I want to remove the wrapping '#hwAddition' so that all elements for the item are removed. How would I go about trying to access the current wrapping div?

Comment: `this.closest('#hwAddition').remove()`. If these divs are repeating though, then you should not be re-using the same ID

Comment: Ok, You went to remove wrapping , div right ?

Comment: Yes I want to remove the wrapping div and ```this.closest('hwAddition').remove()``` gave the error that 'this.closest is not a function'

Comment: also try repeater js it's easy to control elements, https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [parentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) to remove the button and its parent as well.

> In function `removeHWItem()` `this` refers to as which element you are clicking on.

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
function removeHWItem(e) {
   e.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```

```html
<div id="hwAddition">
  <div>
    <div id="itemNumber" style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: large; display: inline-block;">Item #</div>
    <input class="removeItemButton" type="button" value="Remove Item" id="removeItemButton" onclick="removeHWItem(this)" style="display: inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="hwDescription" style="text-decoration: underline;">Description</label>
      <form:textarea id="hwDescription" type="text" class="form-control short" path="hwDescription" name="hwDescription" placeholder="Description" maxlength="100" rows="2" style="resize: none;" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="hwSerialNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Serial
                            #</label>
      <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwSerialNumber" name="hwSerialNumber" placeholder="Serial #" maxlength="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="hwModelNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Model
                            #</label>
      <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwModelNumber" name="hwModelNumber" placeholder="Model #" maxlength="100" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>

<div id="hwAddition">
  <div>
    <div id="itemNumber" style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: large; display: inline-block;">Item #</div>
    <input class="removeItemButton" type="button" value="Remove Item" id="removeItemButton" onclick="removeHWItem(this)" style="display: inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="hwDescription" style="text-decoration: underline;">Description</label>
      <form:textarea id="hwDescription" type="text" class="form-control short" path="hwDescription" name="hwDescription" placeholder="Description" maxlength="100" rows="2" style="resize: none;" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="hwSerialNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Serial
                            #</label>
      <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwSerialNumber" name="hwSerialNumber" placeholder="Serial #" maxlength="100" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="hwModelNumber" style="text-decoration: underline;">Model
                            #</label>
      <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="hwModelNumber" name="hwModelNumber" placeholder="Model #" maxlength="100" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I get the error "cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined"

Comment: @CDAtheProgrammer are you sure your onclick looks like this: `onclick="removeHWItem(this)"` ? You are not adding `this` in your `onclick` thats why.

Comment: @CDAtheProgrammer Glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Answer (score -2):

If you using **jQuery**, use `$(this).parent()`, it is **#itemNumber** selector

Comment: I think there is no dependency on Jquery in the given question.